# Create new Realm List and add items

Tags: json, swift, realm, realm-list

I make a `API` request with `Alamofire` , I then get a response in `JSON` format, I then parse the `JSON` into a `NSDictionary` to get to the data I want.
The data I get is four `Arrays` of different items.
I want to the create a new List in Realm to save these items in.
Here are my Realm Object Classes :

```
class ListOfDefinitions: Object {
 let listOfItems = List<Item>()
}
```

and

```
class Item: Object {

dynamic var AverageCost = Int()
dynamic var Barcode = ""
dynamic var Description = ""
dynamic var InternalUnique = Int()
dynamic var LastCost = Int()
dynamic var LimitToMainRegionUnique = Int()
dynamic var Notes = ""
dynamic var StockCategoryUnique = Int()
dynamic var StockCode = ""
dynamic var StockGroupUnique = Int()
dynamic var UnitDescriptor = ""
}
```

Here is my code on how I handle the JSON response and where I want to save the data in my code.

```
 var newItemInStockList : ListOfDefinitions!   // declared in the class
 let newItemInStock = Item()


.responseJSON { response in



            switch response.result {

            case .Success(let JSON):
               // print("Success with JSON: \(JSON)")

                let response = JSON as! NSDictionary



                let responseParams = response.objectForKey("ResponseParameters") as! NSDictionary
                //print(responseParams)

                //let stockItemGroupList = responseParams.objectForKey("StockItemGroupList")

                let stockItemList = responseParams.objectForKey("StockItemList") as! NSDictionary
                //print(stockItemList)

                let listofDefinitions = stockItemList.objectForKey("ListofDefinitions") as! NSArray
                print(listofDefinitions.count)


                for defJson in listofDefinitions {

                    print(defJson["Description"])

                    someString = defJson["Description"] as! String
                    print(someString)
// Because there are 4 arrays of items this for loop will be red 4 times, each time it is red I want o create a new list and add the items to the list
//  This comment area is where I tried to create a new list and then .append the items in it, but it doesn't work.                   
//                        let newOne = ListOfDefinitions()
//                        
//                        
//                        try! realm.write{
//                            
//                            realm.add(newOne)
//                        }
//                        self.newItemInStock.AverageCost = defJson["AverageCost"] as! Int
//                        self.newItemInStock.Barcode = defJson["Barcode"] as! String
//                        self.newItemInStock.Description = defJson["Description"] as! String
//                        self.newItemInStock.InternalUnique = defJson["InternalUnique"] as! Int
//                        self.newItemInStock.LastCost = defJson["LastCost"] as! Int
//                        self.newItemInStock.LimitToMainRegionUnique = defJson["LimitToMainRegionUnique"] as! Int
//                        self.newItemInStock.Notes = defJson["Notes"] as! String
//                        self.newItemInStock.StockCategoryUnique = defJson["StockCategoryUnique"] as! Int
//                        self.newItemInStock.StockCode = defJson["StockCode"] as! String
//                        self.newItemInStock.StockGroupUnique = defJson["StockGroupUnique"] as! Int
//                        self.newItemInStock.UnitDescriptor = defJson["UnitDescriptor"] as! String
//                        
//                        try! realm.write{
//                            
//                            self.newItemInStockList.listOfItems.append(self.newItemInStock)
//                        }

                }

            case .Failure(let error):
                print("Request failed with error: \(error)")
            }
```

And here is what I get when I print the 4 Arrays

[image]

Comment: When you say "The data I get is four `Arrays` of different items." You mean an array of 4 items?

Comment: Yes it is an Array of 4 Items, each Item containing 
AverageCost = 0;
        Barcode = "";
        Description = "TEST ITEM 2";
        InternalUnique = 2;
        LastCost = 0;
        LimitToMainRegionUnique = "-1";
        Notes = "";
        StockCategoryUnique = 0;
        StockCode = BBCD45785;
        StockGroupUnique = 0;
        UnitDescriptor = Units;

Comment: sorry if it is a bit messy, in a bit of a Crunch

Comment: What do you use to map `JSON` to `Realm Object`?

Comment: self.newItemInStock.AverageCost = defJson["AverageCost"] as! Int

Comment: I commented this out in  the code, because I first have to create a new List, cast the JSON to the Realm Object like so (self.newItemInStock.AverageCost = defJson["AverageCost"] as! Int) and add it to the list inside each loop

Comment: but I can't seem to create a new list

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your sample code, I think the main issue happening here is that you're re-using the same `self.newItemInStock` instance for each object you're adding to the list.

It would be best to create a new `Item` object in the loop as you're going along and append that to the `List` object.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using a combination of AlamofireObjectMapper to handle all your JSON mapping (both ways) https://github.com/tristanhimmelman/AlamofireObjectMapper

and the ListTransform found in ObjectMapper+Realm https://github.com/Jakenberg/ObjectMapper-Realm

They're both available to be installed through cocoapods. Your code will look much cleaner and easier to maintain